# CentOS 7 Upgraded gcc / g++ but can't seem to use it?

Tags: gcc, centos, g++, centos7

I used the [script](https://gist.github.com/jdhao/e3fd77d51f3a95684d2b3354fc61b2ab) to upgrade `gcc/g++` to v5.4.  The script ran successfully and the new libraries were supposedly installed to `/usr/lib64`

Still, when I `gcc --version` it tells me its 4.8.5 still.  There is no gcc directory in `/usr/lib64` and the one in `/usr/lib` only contains a gcc directory folder for 4.8.5

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: When that script did `make install`, look at the output and see where it put stuff. Possibly somewhere in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick you are a hero.  It was installed in /usr/local/bin... So simple.  

THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's an issue with creating a symbolic link to gcc-4.8

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm gcc
sudo ln -s gcc-4.8 gcc
```

then test

```
gcc --version
```

And see if you got it. If not, you can

```
sudo yum remove path/packageName
```

and reinstall

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I bet this would have worked but I was trying to keep the origina 4.8.5 on there as well since it's the highest officially supported on CentOS 7.  
I renamed g++ and gcc to g++-4.8.5 and gcc-4.8.5 and it worked.  I'm sure your  suggestion would of as well